# Avoid repeating code when reusing for multiple value constructor pattern matches

Tags: haskell

Suppose you have a data structure with multiple value constructors, for example a `LogMessage` data structure like so:

```
data LogMessage = Unknown String 
                | LogMessage MessageType TimeStamp String
```

If the message can be parsed properly, it has some extra data and then a `String`. If it can't be parsed, then it's just a catch-all `Unknown String`.

Or suppose you are working with something like an `Either String String`, so that you might be dealing with a `Left String` or a `Right String`.

Now let's say that you want to apply the same processing steps to the underlying data, regardless of which value constructor it resides in.

For example, I might want to detect a certain word within the `LogMessage` strings, so I could have a function like this:

```
detectWord :: String -> LogMessage -> Bool
detectWord s (Unknown m)         = isInfixOf s (map toLower m)
detectWord s (LogMessage _  _ m) = isInfixOf s (map toLower m)
```

or it could just as easily be written to handle `Either String String` as input instead of `LogMessage`.

In both cases, I have to repeat the exact same code (the `isInfixOf ...` part), because I have to extract the underlying data it will operate on differently due to pattern matching on different value constructors.

It is bad that one must repeat / "copy-paste" the code for each different value constructor match.

How does one write these kinds of Haskell functions without copy/paste code? How can I write the underlying logic just once, but then explain how it should be used across many different value constructor patterns?

Simply moving it to a secondary helper function would reduce the character count, but doesn't really solve the issue. For example, the idea below is not substantively any better about "don't repeat yourself" than the first case:

```
helper :: String -> String -> Bool
helper s m = isInfixOf s (map toLower m)

detectWord :: String -> LogMessage -> Bool
detectWord s (Unknown m)        = helper s m
detectWord s (LogMessage _ _ m) = helper s m
```

There again we have to say the same thing for every different pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write a function that gets the message in either case.  Then, you won't need to write separate cases for uses that don't care:

```
getMsg (Unknown m) = m
getMsg (LogMessage _ _ m) = m

detectWord s log = infixOf s (map toLower (getMsg log))
```

Note that *something* is going to have to check the cases of your type, and `getMsg` is about as minimal as it gets along those lines.

Answer (score 4):

### Simple, won't make people hate you

Try using [view patterns](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns).

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

data LogMessage = Unknown String
                | LogMessage MessageType TimeStamp String

stringOfLogMessage :: LogMessage -> String
stringOfLogMessage (Unknown s) = s
stringOfLogMessage (LogMessage _ _ s) = s

detectWord :: String -> LogMessage -> Bool
detectWord needle (stringOfLogMessage -> hay) =
  needle `isInfixOf` map toLower hay
```

### Complicated, might make people hate you

Use [Generics](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC.Generics) and [Generics.Deriving.Lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13.1/docs/Generics-Deriving-Lens.html).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}

module Lib where

import BasePrelude
import Control.Lens
import Generics.Deriving.Lens

data LogMessage = Unknown String
                | LogMessage () () String
                  deriving (Generic)

detectWord :: String -> LogMessage -> Bool
detectWord needle =
  allOf tinplate (isInfixOf needle . map toLower)
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but it seems like you could also just use the helper function you provided. Then it could be `detectWord needle lm = isInfixOf needle (stringOfLogMessage lm)`. The view pattern is nice, I'm just thinking out loud that it looks like it's not necessary. It looks like my confusion was that I did not consider the idea of writing the helper function as a means for abstracting away the pattern matched conversion to string -- I only thought of the helper function in terms of the "right hand side" logic being used.

Comment: I for one tend to find view patterns very confusing. Maybe I'm just not sufficiently accustomed to their syntax, but I can never seem to remember which part goes where.

Comment: the way i think of it: foo x y is really foo (id -> x) (id -> y).

Comment: I think what *I'd* do when designing an abstract datatype is almost certainly to write the appropriate pattern synonyms (once!) with the user's guide open, so users don't have to think about special syntax.